# base 64 encoding: ascii character to be used

Tags: numbers, type-conversion, mime, radix

I wanted to use this tool to convert a sequence of decimal numbers to base64 encoding

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/

if I have a low number such as 5, how do I insert it into the form?

Comment: Base64 encodes *binary* data. It's not really clear what you mean by "convert a sequence of decimal numbers to base64 encoding".

Comment: I suggest you use the option to upload a file containing the non-printable characters.

Comment: I dont have binary data. I have a sequence such as 5,128,256 etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it wasn't a programming problem, but now it can't be answered because the link is broken.